Force a Teams link to open in Sharepoint
My link in Teams will not open in a Sharepoint tab.
I have a list on an MS Teams site that I want to forcibly open in Sharepoint (in the browser).  I need it opened in Sharepoint so users can use the 'search list' feature that Sharepoint has and Teams does not.  Teams search is useless, as it does not allow a list or other custom stuff to be searched.
I've made a page, added the list link to the page and fiddled around with things like this:
<a href="mysharepointsite/list/mylistlisturl.html" target="_blank">Linktomylist</a>

But I can't get this approach to work, the page editor in Sharepoint/Teams is annoyingly limited compared to On Prem and I can't get it to work.
I've also tried using Quick Links / 'open link in a new tab' but this does nothing when the link is opened from within the Teams app.
I don't want to have to use 'Open in Browser', I want to cut that step out:

Any suggestions please?
Research

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-a-new-tab-in-html
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/quicklinks-open-in-a-new-tab/m-p/3035808
https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/09/04/sharepoint-configure-navigation-links-to-open-in-a-new-tab/


Are you using the new version of Teams or Teams (classic)?

I must be using the new version of Teams.  It appears the classic version is due to be discontinued in Oct 2024, there's been no discussion at work about this, so I assume I'm using the new version.

It seems like Teams app opens all internal links within Teams app, not in browser. But here is what worked for me.


I used "Share" button while working with the list in browser
Ensured the link is type of "People with existing access"
Used "Copy Link" button

The link I got was kind of "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/:l:/r/sites/Test_01/Lists/TestList01?e=EwZSY9"
And it worked! I mean when I used this link in a Page - teams opened this link in a new tab in a browser. I tried 3 options - text web-part, link webpart and quick links - all 3 options worked well:


Thanks Vlad, that's cracked it!  Thanks also for the screenshots, very helpful.
